# Unintended loop termination

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

I'm writing a program for class that lowercases a text string. This works for the first character, but when it loops back for the second the beq $10,$0,done line always turns $10 to 0 and terminates the loop. I have no idea why.

```
.text
.globl main
main:
lui $9, 0x1000

loop:
lbu $10,0($9)
sll $0,$0,0

beq $10,$0,done
sll $0,$0,0

addiu $10,$10,0x20
sw  $10,0($9)
addiu $9,$9,1
ori $10,$0,1
j loop

sll $0,$0,0
done: sll $0,$0,0

.data
string: .asciiz "ABCDEFG"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sw  $10,0($9)`  <-- this is wrong

That `sw` should be an `sb`. Otherwise you'll store the 32-bit word `0x000000nn` (where `0xnn` is your character) at `($9)`. Which means that the bytes at `1($9)..3($9)` will all be filled with the value 0. So on the next iteration of the loop you'll load the first of those 0-bytes and exit the loop.

Comment: Perfect, i figured it out myself but thanks for the explanation, i didnt know that part.